# Page/2 posts don't load and give 404

Tags: 404-error

I load 10 posts on my home.php and I have the 'posts_nav_link()' function to acces to latest entries. But when I click on the previous entries, the link redirect me to mysite.com/page/2 and give me a 404 error.

Could you help me please Thanks ?

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : 
                query_posts(
                        array(
                            'post_type' => array(
                                'etude',
                                'new'
                            )
                        )
                    );?>


                <?php while (have_posts()) :
                    the_post(); ?>

                <div class="box1 clearfix" style="margin-top: 7px;">
                    <div class="post clearfix">
                        <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        <p class="txt0"><?php the_time('d F Y'); ?> dans <a href="<?php echo site_url(get_post_type());?>"><?php echo get_post_type(); ?></a> // <?php comments_popup_link(__('No Comments &#187;', woothemes), __('1 Comment &#187;',woothemes), __('% Comments &#187;',woothemes)); ?></p>

                    <?php the_content(__('<span class="continue">Continue Reading</span>',woothemes)) ?>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <div class="navigation nav clearfix">
                    <div class="fl"><?php posts_nav_link() ?></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: We need more info. Can you show us the code that you are using for your home page? Also, double-check your permalink settings and try saving them again.

Comment: The posts_nav_link() redirect me to localhost/mysite/page/2 and give me a 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use `query_posts()` :). See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/9364) for more detailed explanation of why not, and the alternatives.

In this instance, remove your `query_posts()` and instead in a plug-in, (or functions php).

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse57229_change_query_for_main_page');
function wpse57229_change_query_for_main_page( $query ){
     if( $query->is_main_query() && is_front_page() ){
          $query->set('post_type',array('etude','new'));
     }
}
```